# Handling '$' in Table name when using hibernate tools to do code generation

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Hibernate tools (eclipse plugin) to do code generation to create the POJO & th hbm, But table name that contain '$' will make problem. e.g., for table 'Buyer$Souce' will generate a class named 'Buyer.souce' 
is there any way to solve this problem? I want to just ignore the '$' ,e.g., 'Buyer$source' generate 'BuyerSouce.java'

Thanks

Comment: sounds like a horrible naming scheme for your tables to me...

Comment: yes yes, but i can't change it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a directly with the Hibernate Tools Plugin.  You could generate everything except Buyer$Source and manually code the class for BuyerSource.  Use an annotation  (or modify the hbm) to set the table name.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Buyer$Souce")
public class BuyerSouce  {
//...
}
```